# Highcharts plot band to last datetime value from spreadsheet data

Tags: highcharts

I built a column chart with a plot band

```
        plotBands: [{ 
                  zIndex: 1,
                  to: Date.UTC(2020,4,6),
                  from: Date.UTC(2020,3,30),
                  color: 'rgb(217, 217, 217, .4)',

    }],
```

and a zone with a different colors for the x values:

```
                    zones: [{
                        value: Date.UTC(2020,3,30),
                        color: '#003f6e'
                    }, {
                        color: '#999999'
                    }]
```

see [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Joh_Christ/eznubmdv/)

Now I want both to cover the range of the last 7 days from data. The data comes from a google spreadsheet and is updated continuously. I tried something like this:

```
        plotBands: [{ 
                  zIndex: 1,
                  to: this.series.data[this.series.data.length-1].x,
                  from: this.series.data[this.series.data.length-7].x,
                  color: 'rgb(217, 217, 217, .4)',

    }],
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **data.complete** callback to set the plotLines and the zones dynamically by updating the **xAxis** and **series**.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/m0vdtjzo/

```
complete() {
  let xColumn = this.columns[0];

  chart.xAxis[0].update({
    plotBands: [{
      zIndex: 1,
      to: xColumn[xColumn.length - 1],
      from: xColumn[xColumn.length - 7],
      color: 'rgb(217, 217, 217, .4)',
    }]
  })

  chart.series[0].update({
    zones: [{
      value: xColumn[xColumn.length - 7],
      color: '#003f6e'
    }, {
      color: '#999999'
    }]
  })
}
```

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/data.complete

API: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Axis#update